# Android services and Intent filters

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-8.0-oreo

When we declare something like this in the manifest, is it guaranteed that the service will be executed (if it is not already running) on receiving an intent of that type? Does this work the same way on Android Oreo 8.0?

```
    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it guaranteed that the service will be executed (if it is not already running) on receiving an intent of that type?

"Guaranteed" is a strong term. *Generally* your statement is true. Scenarios where it will not be include:

- If somebody tries starting the service using an implicit `Intent`, one with just that action string. Most likely a device will have several services with that `<intent-filter>`, in which case Android will just pick one of those services to start. Note that *binding* using an implicit `Intent` is banned on Android 5.0+, to avoid this sort of situation.
- If you disabled the component at runtime using `PackageManager` and `setComponentEnabledSetting()`.

> Does this work the same way on Android Oreo 8.0?

I am not aware of any changes in the behavior of `<intent-filter>` on `<service>` in Android 8.0. There are changes to *services* in Android 8.0 (e.g., cannot start a service from the background), but those changes do not depend on the existence of an `<intent-filter>`.

Comment: If the service is not running and an Intent is received, the service will start from backgorund, right? Since Android 8.0 doesn't allow this as you've said, what should I expect? Thanks

Comment: @notGeek: The determination of "background" is from the perspective of who calls `startService()` or `bindService()`, not from the perspective of the service itself.

Answer (score -1):

It depends Upon what type of Service you are using .

1.
**Foreground**-: A foreground service performs some operation that is noticeable to the user

2: **Background**:- Background service performs an operation that isn't directly noticed by the user. For example, if an app used a service to compact its storage, that would usually be a background service.

```
Note: If your app targets API level 26 or higher, the system imposes restrictions on running background services when the app itself is not in the foreground. In most cases like this, your app should use a scheduled job instead.
```

3. **Bound**
    A service is bound when an application component binds to it by calling bindService().

So as you see on note for android Oreo or higher there are certain limitations on Background service. For More info on topic you can read [Here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html).